# Blowfish file encryption without keygenerator

Tags: java, encryption, blowfish, secret-key

How do I encrypt my files without using the KeyGenerator using the Blowfish Algorithm?

here's part of my code

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(plain);

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(copy);
CipherOutputStream out2 = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
while (fis.read(buffer)>=0) {
    out2.write(buffer);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a key you can provide it using the SecretKeySpec like this:

```
byte[] key = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
SecretKey keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "Blowfish");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec);
```

Comment: Thannks for your reply, now, i am browsing for a file to encrypt using the JFileChooser(); my problem now is passing this file to the encryption method and prompting the user to enter the key for encryption using an inputDialog, how do i achieve this please?

Comment: @NehemiahLimo NEVER EVER use a static hardcoded key. If the user is to enter a password, you rather use a key derivation function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2 with a random salt